Redirect all old 404 aspx pages on a Apache server to homepage
In GSC I have many 404 error of old .aspx pages but now I redesigned the website with apache+php. I need a command for redirect all urls that ends with .aspx to root (also urls with queries). In example all www.mywebsite.com/anyfolder/...etc/anypage.aspx should be redirected to www.mywebsite.com
I have tried this :
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.aspx$ https://www.mywebsite.it/ [R=301,L]

but it seems not work. Any suggestion ?

Although not what you are asking for, I would actually encourage you to NOT do this. The 404 exists to let systems know "this is gone", where as "301" means "this has moved", which is not the case. Also, when users click a link and receive something they weren't looking for, they sometimes "try again", and if that fails, and the link was important enough, they email saying your site is broken. So instead of this, I'd recommend having a nice clean 404 page that lets both users and robots know that the content is intentionally gone.

In addition, I'd log the 404s and from that log determine the links the actually have valid replacement equivalents.

"(also urls with queries)" - why do you have a RewriteCond that only allows for an empty query string then? And why the need to check on the REDIRECT_STATUS to begin with?
